# Idiomatic way to memoize or lazy evaluate using `Cell` and `RefCell`

Tags: rust

The code below works. It evaluates `x` and `ys` lazily and caches into `Foo::x: Cell`, `Foo::ys: RefCell` respectively.

However, I feel there might be a better way to do it. I dislike I have to make a wrapper `CacheVecGuard` so that on the call site I can use `self.borrow_ys()` instead of the lengthy `&self.ys.borrow().1`.

How can I improve this piece of code?

Are there any canonical snippets to do lazy evaluation or memoization that is suitable in this case? (I am aware of `lazy_static` which doesn't fit)

```
use std::cell::{RefCell, Cell, Ref};
use std::ops::Deref;

struct CacheVecGuard<'a>(Ref<'a, (bool, Vec<f64>)>);

impl<'a> Deref for CacheVecGuard<'a> {
    type Target = [f64];

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &(self.0).1
    }
}

fn pre_calculate_x(x: f64) -> f64 {
    x
}

fn pre_calculate_ys(x: f64, ys: &mut [f64]) {
    for i in 0..ys.len() {
        ys[i] += 1.0;
    }
}

struct Foo {
    pub a: f64,
    x: Cell<Option<f64>>,
    ys: RefCell<(bool, Vec<f64>)>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(a: f64) -> Self {
        Self {
            a,
            x: Cell::new(None),
            ys: RefCell::new((false, vec![0.0; 10])),
        }
    }

    fn get_x(&self) -> f64 {
        match self.x.get() {
            None => {
                let x = pre_calculate_x(self.a);
                self.x.set(Some(x));
                println!("Set x to {}", x);
                x
            }
            Some(x) => x,
        }
    }

    fn borrow_ys(&self) -> CacheVecGuard {
        {
            let (ref mut ready, ref mut ys) = *self.ys.borrow_mut();
            if !*ready {
                pre_calculate_ys(self.a, ys);
                println!("Set ys to {:?}", ys);
                *ready = true;
            }
        }
        CacheVecGuard(self.ys.borrow())
    }

    fn clear_cache(&mut self) {
        *(&mut self.ys.borrow_mut().0) = false;
        self.x.set(None);
    }

    pub fn test(&self) -> f64 {
        self.borrow_ys()[0] + self.get_x()
    }

    pub fn set_a(&mut self, a: f64) {
        self.a = a;
        self.clear_cache();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new(1.0);
    println!("{}", foo.test());
    foo.set_a(3.0);
    println!("{}", foo.test());
}
```

It prints

```
Set ys to [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Set x to 1
2
Set ys to [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
Set x to 3
5
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=17ea59652cd6cbb4b46974f4d1c7a95d&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you need the ability to clear the cache means that you must have a guard. Otherwise, a call to `set_a` could invalidate a bare reference returned earlier by `borrow_ys`. The only way the compiler can verify that this doesn't happen is by returning a guard and borrowing from the guard instead.

If you can do away with the ability to clear the cache, you could use the `LazyCell` type from the [`lazycell`](https://crates.io/crates/lazycell) crate instead.